# Auto resize <div> height to remaining space in view port /window

Tags: php, css, html

I have the follwing HTML code:

```
<html>
    <BODY>
        <DIV ID="holder">
            <DIV ID="head_area">HEAD CONTENT GOES HERE....</DIV>
            <DIV ID="main_area">BODY CONTENT GOES HERE</DIV>
            <DIV ID="foot_area">FOOT CONTENT GOES HERE...<>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The CSS applied to this script is as follows:

```
#holder{
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
}
#head_area{
    height:45px;
}
#main_area{
    height:???;            /*Set such that its height adjusts itself to occupy rest pixels of view prt browser pane leftover after placing '#head_area' & '#foot_area' (i.e. height = total height of pane in px - (45px + 20px)*/
    overflow:scroll;
}
#foot_area{
    height:20px;
}
```

What should I do in CSS to set the `#main_area` height to occupy the remaining space, screen resolution independent , after placing `#head_area` & `#foot_area` in position... In other words, The `#head_area` & `#foot_area` are always visible in default but on zooming ('ctrl'+'+') it should move out of pane as usual...

Thanks...

Comment: Why didn't you selected the answer on your last question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 100% height isn't going to work in the way you want it to as the parent containers don't have heights set. You could set both html and body to height:100%, then use calc as suggested, but you'll need to offer fallbacks for older browsers that don't support calc.

You could use JavaScript to find the window height, then adjust the height of #main_area to equal that measurement minus the heights of #head_area and #foot_area. You'd need to set this on page load, window resize and orientation change.

The easiest way might be to simply to use absolute positioning.

```
#head_area {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:45px;
}
#main_area {
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;       /* position below header */
    bottom:20px;    /* make room for footer */
    overflow:scroll;
}
#foot_area {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:20px;
}
```

You say that

> The #head_area & #foot_area are always visible in default but on
>   zooming ('ctrl'+'+') it should move out of pane as usual...

but that doesn't make sense with #main_area using overflow:scroll. When should it scroll, and when should it get larger (while still scrolling the overflow?) and move the footer out of the viewport?

Comment: When the content within `#main_area` is more than the space available within it (`#main_area`) it should scroll (i.e. 100 lines of text in font size 12pt)... And when the user zoms in a specific area it should push `#head_area` & `#foot_area` out of view to alow free space within d window to view enlarged text (The `#head_area` & `#foot_area` should not cover up the pane and hide the enlarged text as in wikipedia.cm on zoom the side panels zoom in occupying 80% 0f view and a thin area is left for main content....)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)**

```
height:calc(100% - 65px);
```

Notes from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

> Note: The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace.

Comment: Worked This time.... Didn't Know 'spaces' mandatory around operator... Thanks !!!!

Comment: IE-10 on Win8 x64 getting Hanged with this code, Firefox Nightly v30.0a1(2014-03-06) doesn't support...

Comment: @Anirban : it's better to use jquery to do it

Answer (score 0):

To make the footer stay at the bottom you could to take it out of the wrapper, for example:

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1>Logo Here</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="content_main"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></div>
        </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer Stays Here Woop Woop</p>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS you set the body of the document to height 100%, then child elements can use that space

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Then the CSS for the footer would be something like:

```
#footer {
   position:relative;
   height:75px; //the height of the footer
   margin-top:-75px; //pull the footer back onto screen
   width:100%;
   background:#ccc; 
}
```

JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/9SuGG/

### Edit, Here's a better example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8xx9/))

With a fixed header and footer and scrollable center section, using a little jQuery to change the height of the overflow wrapper (added abit of styling to it also):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background:#111;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:415px;
    margin:0;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    min-height:92px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #2A2A2A;
    background:#0E0E0E;
    box-shadow:0 0 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
}

#header h1 {
    font-size:4em;
    font-weight:700;
    margin-left:10px;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 0 #000;
}

#content_wrap {
    width:100%;
}

#content_main {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:0 5px;
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #2A2A2A;
    background:#0E0E0E;
    box-shadow:0 0 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
    padding:0 5px;
}

#footer p {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:4px;
}
/*example make the text big, to show side bar*/
#content_main{font-size:200%}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#content_main').height($(window).height() - 120);
    });
    $('#content_main').height($(window).height() - 120);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content_wrap">
        <div id="content_main">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec suscipit libero. Vivamus nunc 
        sapien, pellentesque vitae dui id, pretium volutpat ligula. Proin varius eros non fringilla tincidunt.
        Cras dignissim ligula molestie lobortis placerat. Donec at imperdiet ligula, sit amet sodales eros.
        Nam tempus lobortis urna ut porta. Pellentesque pulvinar justo ac est faucibus, sit amet tristique 
        nunc tristique. Curabitur sit amet accumsan dolor. Vivamus eu commodo diam, ullamcorper pharetra neque.
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec suscipit libero. Vivamus nunc 
        sapien, pellentesque vitae dui id, pretium volutpat ligula. Proin varius eros non fringilla tincidunt.
        Cras dignissim ligula molestie lobortis placerat. Donec at imperdiet ligula, sit amet sodales eros.
        Nam tempus lobortis urna ut porta. Pellentesque pulvinar justo ac est faucibus, sit amet tristique 
        nunc tristique. Curabitur sit amet accumsan dolor. Vivamus eu commodo diam, ullamcorper pharetra neque.
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec suscipit libero. Vivamus nunc 
        sapien, pellentesque vitae dui id, pretium volutpat ligula. Proin varius eros non fringilla tincidunt.
        Cras dignissim ligula molestie lobortis placerat. Donec at imperdiet ligula, sit amet sodales eros.
        Nam tempus lobortis urna ut porta. Pellentesque pulvinar justo ac est faucibus, sit amet tristique 
        nunc tristique. Curabitur sit amet accumsan dolor. Vivamus eu commodo diam, ullamcorper pharetra neque.
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum By Lawrence Cherone</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```